# call and read external JS file - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an external (on a server) JS file I am calling and need to read.
This is for Captcha use.

I am having an issue since the `TlvJs` object is undefined while calling the JS file. 
When debugging, I have noticed that the `$(document).ready` is being executed before the `TlvJS` was actually declared.

When using the files locally (keeping them in `assets` folder), first, the `TlvJS` is being declared and just then the  `$(document).ready`.

How can I make the `TlvJS` object declared first, even when the file is calling externally?
Please note, I can't control the order of the objects inside this `JS` file.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //select all controls
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div[tjs-control]');

    //iterate thru all found controls
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var elm = elements[i];

        switch ($(elm).attr('js-control')) {
            //Captcha control
            case "TlvJs.UI.Captcha":

                var cap = TlvJs.UI.Captcha($(elm).attr('id'));
                var options = $(elm).attr('js-options');

                setInstanceProps(options, cap);
                cap.url = SetClientProtocol(cap.url);
                cap.initCaptcha();
                $.prototype.Captcha = cap;
                break;
        }
    }
    
});


var TlvJs = {
    UI: {
        Captcha: function (tagId) {
            var cap;
            cap = Captcha(tagId);
            return cap;
        },
        FileUploader: function (options) {
            return FileUploader(options);
        }
    },
    Utils: {

    },
    Navigation: {

    }
};
```

Currently, I am adding the `JS` files manually inside a `.ts` file since when adding the Js files inside the `index.html` the `elm` element in the JS file is undefined. That way, the Html page wasn't actually loaded yet.

The first way I have tried (with `index.html`) which cause the "unknown" `elm` element:

```html
 <script src="http://xxx/Services/CaptchaServicesDistributed/Scripts/TlvJs-Captcha.js"></script>
  <script src="http://xxx/Services/CaptchaServicesDistributed/Scripts/TlvBaseJs.js"></script>
```

The second (and current) way is :

```js
 let tlvBaseScript = document.createElement("script");
        tlvBaseScript.defer = true;
        tlvBaseScript.src = this._configService.getTlvBaseScriptUrl();
        tlvBaseScript.type = "text/javascript";
        
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tlvBaseScript);
```

Comment: How exactly are you adding the .js file in the index.html file? If you are adding it async, you may have issues. If you are adding it with a plain old script tag and no other modifiers, the file should be loading completely. The fairly standard way of going about what you are asking is to just include a script tag in the head of the document. I have seen the script itself cause the issue you are discussing (things aren't ready) because it manipulates itself internally, but that would mean changing the script, not changing how you load it.

Comment: let me edit my question .. I have actually done both.

Comment: have you tried using defer when loading the script or using import statements? Otherwise you could switch your trigger from document.ready to a deferred script, since those get executed after the page load is complete.

Comment: I have tried using either `defer` and import statement. it didn't work

Comment: I would probably do two things: open the debugger and carefully inspect the loading (in network tab) and call stack (in sources), and/or, grab that script, put it on a second web server I have control over, put some console logs in it, and load it from there (as a test). If you are loading that script in a plain old script tag in the index file, then you should see the script fully load in the network tag before the processing starts and it should be ready. If not, something may be going on in the script itself. It may be waiting for some kind of input or argument, an event, who knows.

Comment: In the debugger (or by grabbing and putting a log in it), it'd be interesting to see when exactly document.ready fires in the script (or if it is at all). It may not be doing exactly what you expect.

Comment: nice. I'll try it thanks

Comment: document.ready fires first...